# Django Celery stuck as Pending

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am attempting to use `celery` within my **Django** app to speed up the processing time of a function and I can't get it to work correctly.  I am using **RabbitMQ**.

My **`tasks.py`**

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task,current_task
from myapp.celery import app

@app.task
def add(x,y):
    
    for i in range(25000000):
        a = x+y
    
    return x+y
```

My **`python code`**

```py
def test_multi_func():
    x = 5
    y = 10
    i = 15
    print(f"start = {time.perf_counter()}")
    while i > 0:
        g = add.delay(x,y)
        result = add.AsyncResult(g)
        i -= 1
    print(result.backend)
    print(result.status)
    print(f"end = {time.perf_counter()}")
    print(f"g = {g.get()}")
    print(f"x = {x} ; y = {y}")
```

My **`settings.py`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_select2',
    'chartjs',
    'django_material_icons',
    'material',
    'django_celery_results',
    'celery_progress',
    'django_apscheduler'
]

BROKER_URL = 'django://'
result_backend = 'django-db'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
result_persistent = True
task_result_expires = None
send_events = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
```

my **`celery.py`**

```py
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

app = Celery('myapp',
             backend='amqp://guest@localhost:15672/',
             broker='amqp://guest@localhost:15672/',
             include=['myapp.tasks'])

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')


app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

What am I doing wrong ?
I have a difficult time understanding this.  It triggers the `test_multi_func()` and then is stuck as pending within **RabbitMQ** and nothing happens.  Would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand what I need to do differently.  I've tried many different iterations of different code I could find online and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your celery configuration has many conflicts, and I'm wondering how you're running the worker. Specifically,

1. In your `settings.py,` you're mixing the legacy and new styles of configuring Celery. The lowercased configuration settings are preferred for Celery 4 and beyond: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings
2. You've configured the broker URLs twice (`amqp://guest@localhost:15672/` and `amqp://localhost`), and you've configured two different result backends.
3. You've passed in the configuration to the Celery instance three times, and the settings are stomping on each other. Specifically, when we pass your settings directly into the Celery class is *should* look like the following:

```py
app = Celery('myapp',
             backend_url='amqp://guest@localhost:15672/',
             broker_backend='amqp://guest@localhost:15672/',
             include=['myapp.tasks'])
```

You can also create the Celery instance and configure it in two steps if you prefer:

```
app = Celery('myapp')
app.conf.update(broker_url='amqp://guest@localhost:15672/',
                result_backend='amqp://guest@localhost:15672/')
```